# Invalid cast exception when audit logging from multiple tables to a single EF audit table

Tags: ef-core-2.1, audit.net

My application uses `Audit.NET` with `Audit.EntityFramework` for audit logging data changes. For the purpose of facilitation the creation of audit log / data changes visualisation, I decided to log changes from a few tables into a single one. Long story short: I defined a state machine for my item and I'm logging whats happening with it from when it first appears in my system till when I dispose it.

In order to demonstrate the issues that I'm struggling with, I create a test REST app and made it available on [GitHub repository](https://github.com/damir-dezeljin/DotNetAudit-test).

The application tracks the lifetime of articles, where an article can come to the system by:

- an article is directly added and linked to a publication - in short, it is **ACCEPTED**
- an article proposal is added - in short, it is **PROPOSED**
- a PROPOSED article can be accepted for addition to a publication - in short, it is **ACCEPT_PROPOSAL**

For some more details, check the `public enum ProcessAction`.

### How to reproduce

1. Clone the repo
2. Create the DB and the user - creation SQL code is contained in a comment in `TestDbContext.cs`
3. Run the DB migration
4. Start the application
5. Call all endpoints from `TestsController.cs` in the order they appear - here are direct links (`HTTP GET`):

   1. Mew Publication: http://localhost:5000/tests/publication/add?name=New%20Publication
   2. Add Article: http://localhost:5000/tests/article/add?type=ReviewArticle&title=Test%20article%202018&note=My%20test%20note&publicationId=1
   3. Propose an article: http://localhost:5000/tests/proposal/add?type=ReviewArticle&title=Test proposal 1&note=Proposal%20note%201
   4. Accept the article proposal (NOTE: the article ID may differ on your system): http://localhost:5000/tests/accept/1?publicationId=2

### Issues

1. The last call is throwing the following exception:

   ```
   InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
   'si.dezo.test.DotNetAudit.Models.Article' to type
   'si.dezo.test.DotNetAudit.Models.ArticleProposal'.
   ```
2. I commented out a few lines of code in `TestDbContext.cs` and marked it as

   > NOTE: the below is not working

Am I doing something wrong or is it a limitation or a bug of the library?

Is there a way around the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the library is supporting only one action for each Target type (audit type).

When you call `.Map` with an action like this:

```
.Map<Article, Audit_Article>((evt, entry, auditTbl) => { /*some action*/ })
```

It will store the action related to the type `Audit_Article`, but your next call:

```
.Map<ArticleProposal, Audit_Article>((item, auditTbl) => { /*overriding action*/ })
```

will override your previous action for any type that maps to `Audit_Article`.

So my initial recommendation is to use the common action via `.AuditEntityAction<IAudit>`. Is that causing you any issues?

I think it's possible to extend the library to allow mapping multiple types to the same target type with independent actions for each. I will take a look.

## UPDATE

This has been implemented on Audit.EntityFramework version 13.2.0, you can now have multiple entities mapping to the same audit type with independent action for each.

- [Some documentation](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#map-multiple-entity-types-to-the-same-audit-type-with-independent-actions)
- [Sample code](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/test/Audit.EntityFramework.Core.UnitTest/EfCore21Tests.cs#L29)

Comment: I though the issue is caused by a limitation in the library, but I didn't dig into the lib itself as I'm not so fluent with C# yet. Also, I wasn't able to get the `.AuditEntryAction<IAudit>` working and can't remember right now what issue I faced. Anyway, I came up to a work-around that I'll push to GitHub and comment here later. The mentioned work-around solves my problem at the moment, so I can proceed with my work. Nevertheless, I'll try to get the `.AuditEntryAction<IAudit>` working as well at a later stage. Last I would vote for the improvement of the lib to support log to single table :)

Comment: I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/175) for this and will work on the change. Regards

Comment: This has been implemented on version 13.2.0, you can now have multiple entities mapping to the same audit type with independent action for each. [Sample code](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/test/Audit.EntityFramework.Core.UnitTest/EfCore21Tests.cs#L29)

Comment: I implemented a work-around solution by using one-to-one table audit logging and aggregating multiple audit tables into a view which I mapped to a DbContext using `DbQuery` - the work-around is tagged `View_WorkAround`.  Thanks @thepirat000, I'll check the update you mentioned as well.